# Can we use SonarQube to scan Terraform scripts with Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: azure, sonarqube, terraform

Can we use SonarQube to scan Terraform code (to create Azure infrastructure such as RBAC, PIM, allowed locations etc) for error and vulnerabilities with Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines?

I found some  link but not sure?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jdamata/sonarqube/latest/docs/resources/sonarqube_qualitygate_project_association

Answer (score 9):

I confirm SonarSource (SonarQube, SonarCloud, SonarLint) doesn't provide yet any feature to scan IaC files (Terraform, CloudFormation, ...). This is part of our 2021 roadmap to bring features to secure Cloud Native apps which include to raise issues on your IaC files. The work just started on our side, so don't expect this to come soon but more starting from Q3.

Edit 2022-01:
SonarQube and SonarCloud now support analysis of CloudFormation and Terraform for AWS + Azure (GPC is coming in Q1 2022).
See the announcements for details:

- https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-2/
- https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-3/

Comment: Where are the doc!? I can't find anything explaining how to actually use sonarcloud to scan terraform files. Do I just create a new project and it reads the source code automatically?

Comment: Looks like SonarQube started to support TerraForm. Please take a look at their documentation  https://www.sonarsource.com/knowledge/languages/terraform/

Answer (score 1):

There is no SonarQube plugin for analyzing Terraform code.
You can use Terrascan or TFLint as static analysis tool.

https://github.com/accurics/terrascan

https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint

Comment: they just do syntax corrcetion and Tflint does not work extensively with azure , am i corrcet here ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one ==> oak9 ([www.oak9.io](http://www.oak9.io)) . It focuses on securing your application architecture by analyzing your IaC. It has a number of features including out-of-the-box security and compliance blueprints, integrations across CI/CD toolsets & code-repositories, integrations with different cloud service providers and a lot more. Full disclosure - I work on the security team here

Comment: does oak9 supports only terraform?

Comment: The link is dead.